# Spring Redis list entry - save extra call to set TTL with RedisTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I am using `RedisTemplate` in my Spring application in order to store lists in my Redis server. I would like to set expiration TTL for the keys I insert to Redis. I am using `RedisTemplate` for pushing values to the lists stored in Redis and then setting their TTL:

```
redisTemplate.opsForList().rightPush(key, value);
redisTemplate.expire(key, 60, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Is there a way to avoid the extra call to set the TTL for each key being inserted? Is there a way to set the TTL together with the insertion or maybe set a default TTL in Redis?